# CorePlot; How to skip data when using doubleForPlot instead of numberForPlot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a `CPTScatterPlot` with a huge amount of data. I have found that I could reduce the memory overhead (and thus time) by using `doubleForPlot` instead of `numberForPlot` in CorePlot.

But when using `numberForPlot` I have the option to return `nil` if some data are missing. CorePlot will then make a break in the graph and not connect the neighbor points.

Is the same possible when using `doubleForPlot`? Is there some exceptional value that I can return and the CorePlot will treat this as a missing point?

Thanks Eric! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `NAN` for missing values.

Comment: Excellent Eric - maybe that returning of nil/NAN should be put in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try an empty c array? Theoretically should work.

- @return A retained C array of data points.

-(double *)doublesForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;

Comment: Hi and thanks. I am using the single-point version `double(s)ForPlot` without the s. So only possible to return a double. For the version with the s I might be able to return `nil` but then no data points will be plotted.