# Scatter plot - Connect points even when there is no data in between

Tags: ios, core-plot

In my graph i have x-axis data to be shown as months in year like

```
arrXData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Jan",@"Feb", @"Mar",@"Apr",@"May", @"Jun", @"Jul",@"Aug", @"Sep", @"Oct", @"Nov", @"Dec",nil];
```

And Y axis Data as

```
arrYData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"25",@"30", @"35",@"40",@"50", @"55", @"65",@"70", @"75", @"80", @"85", @"85",  nil];
```

By using the above static values i am able to plot the scatter plot using core plot.

While doing it dynamically my arrYData will change. I may get some values as nulls.

For example i may not have data for a month “May”. In this case my plot getting broke at the month May. Instead i want to connect the points at April and June neglecting the May value.
(Note: I should have all the fields on x-axis even though there is no data for some of the months)

Can some one suggest me how can i do that. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684234/coreplot-how-to-skip-data-when-using-doubleforplot-instead-of-numberforplot ?

Comment: Hi Larme, thanks for the response. But that is not fulfilling my requirement. My graph should not break, rather it should connect the neighbor points.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the x-y pairs with NULL values from your data before sending it to the plot. For the given example, return 11 from `-numberOfRecordsForPlot:` and skip the values for "May" in both data arrays.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the answer. But I still need "May" on my X-axis, i should not remove the fields with no values. So i should keep the May as it is and i need to connect the points of April and June. How can i do this?

Comment: The axis labels are independent of the plot data. Just don't include a value for "May" in the plot data.